# Birt graph drill through on date range

Tags: date, graph, birt, drillthrough

Hopefully someone can put me out of my misery here as i have been trying this on and off for a week or 2 now.

I have design a graph which groups installs by date and status.  so i have a graph that will show in Aug 23 there may be 30 COMPLETE, 12 CANCELLED, 3 ACTIVE.  thats all well and good.

What im trying to do is when i click on the ACTIVE bar for example, it will show the 3 ACTIVE jobs but it doesnt...I can only seem to get it to work on a day basis. so if i ungroup them by month/ year and just have it as days, it shows me.  Issue there is i have a graph with THOUSANDS of bars.

How can i get the graph to get the min date within that month and the max date within that month and then show me everything between those dates?

Sorry if i have rambled a bit, if you need any more info let me know.

Thanks,

Mike.

I have tried updating the target report with a 2 and from date as well as using a function to try get the min/max date to pass through but it doesnt like that